# Using declared scalar variable within quotes when executing a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Pretty new to stored procedures so not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I've got a pre-built stored procedure that shows customers, addresses, and a balances, etc. and trying to enter some ID's in it via declaring them as scalar variables beforehand (if I can get this working like I want I'm going to try to use it in a loop to run several customers at once through the stored procedure).

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @CustomerIDToHandle int
DECLARE @LocationIDToHandle int

SET @CustomerIDToHandle = 5885
SET @LocationIDToHandle = 3221

EXEC dbo.OpeningBalance_rpt 
         @i_Params=N'((Customer.CustomerID = ''@CustomerIDToHandle'') AND (Location.LocationID = ''@LocationIDToHandle'')) AND 
  ((Company.CompanyID = ''1'')) AND ((Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''1'') OR  (Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''2'') 
  OR  (Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''3''))',
         @i_OrderBy=N' ORDER BY Customer.AccountNo',
         @i_NegativeBalance = 1,
         @i_PositiveBalance = 1,
         @i_ZeroBalance = 1,
         @i_TranDate = '2021-09-23 00:00:00',
         @i_LimitOption = 0
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@CustomerIDToHandle' to data type int.

I suspect it's treating `@CustomerIDToHandle` as a string of literally '@CustomerIDToHandle' and not '5885'.  I'm not sure how I can get it to recognize it as '5885'?

The following script works and gives me the output that I want, when I manually put in the values.

```
EXEC dbo.OpeningBalance_rpt 
         @i_Params=N'((Customer.CustomerID = ''5885'') AND (Location.LocationID = ''3221'')) 
                     AND ((Company.CompanyID = ''1'')) 
                     AND ((Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''1'') OR  (Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''2'') OR (Utility.UtilityStatusID = ''3''))',
         @i_OrderBy = N' ORDER BY Customer.AccountNo',
         @i_NegativeBalance = 1,
         @i_PositiveBalance = 1,
         @i_ZeroBalance = 1,
         @i_TranDate = '2021-09-23 00:00:00',
         @i_LimitOption = 0
```

Comment: The above looks like you are injecting a `WHERE` into your query; most certainly this is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) and a significant security vulnerability. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Variables cannot cross scopes that way. It seems your procedure is using a rather horrifying approach to dynamic SQL where you can just stuff in anything you please, so this is probably wide open to SQL injection. You'd have to ask the creator if they had any vision at all about parameters, other than these too being interpolated into strings for another delicious layer of dynamic SQL. If you *are* the creator... it's not too late to turn back; [here](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is a nice reference.

Comment: I'm not the creator, and unfortunately don't have access to modify the stored the procedure. Thank you for letting me know they cannot cross scopes this way and also of the security vulnerability.

Comment: I would certainly suggest you speak to whomever can then, @Fettster777 . I dread to think what would have to you passed something like `N'1 = 1; DROP TABLE Customer;--'` for the parameter `@i_Params`.

Comment: Writing dynamic sql requires a mastery of basic tsql. I suggest you create a local variable for each parameter you need to pass to the stored procedure and then populate those variables as needed. That will help you debug your code and the inevitable typos you will create within the parameter strings themselves. Some formatting on your part would greatly help others read and understand your code.

Comment: Short sample correction: `set @p1 = N'((Customer.CustomerID = ' + cast(@CustomerIDToHandle as varchar(..)) + ... `. Notice the concatenation - you embed the ID value into the string itself. I removed the single quotes around the ID value since it seems likely that column is numeric. CONCAT is an option for composing strings using different datatypes as well and avoids issues with the problematic "+" operator. This answers your question but it is FAR from a recommendation.